# Jquery - draggable - check from where is picked up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

how can i get id element from where is picked up elemet draggable?

```
<div id="droppable1">
    <div id="draggable">DRAG ME</div>
</div>
<div id="droppable2"></div>
```

User will be move div id draggable(DRAG ME) to element div droppable2.
i need to check from where is picked up. I can`t use parent(), becouse always show id draggable1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no ready-made way to do this, but it isn't that hard to implement.

Basically you need to store the initial parent on the `#draggable` element, then every time the `drop` event occurs you need to update the value. To make this a little easier the `drop` event provides handy access to the element being drag/dropped via the `ui.draggable` property.

A very simple implementation would be as follows.

**HTML**

```
<div id="droppable1" class="droppable">droppable1
    <div id="draggable" data-from-parent='droppable1'>
        From:  <span class="from"></span><br>
        To: <span class="to"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="droppable2" class="droppable">droppable2</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#draggable").draggable();
$(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui)
    {
        ui.draggable.find(".from").text(ui.draggable.data("from-parent"));
        ui.draggable.find(".to").text($(this).attr("id"));
        ui.draggable.data("from-parent", $(this).attr("id"));
    }
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FS79e/) showing this code in action.